# Why does reducer return undefined when returning false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have written a reducer that keeps track of a form to see  if it is submitted successfully

```
const submitted = (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SUBMITTED':
        console.log('seting submit');
        return false;
      case 'SUBMITTED':
        return true;
      default: 
        return state;
    }
};
```

the state returns undefined when I console.log the state on the component side. However I get true value when I change the return value to true. Does redux not allow states the false boolean value??

```
export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  submitted,
  test
});

// on the component side

function mapStateToProps({ submitted }) {
    return {
        submitted
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { submitStudentData })(StudentForm);
```

Comment: Where do you see undefined first and how do you open your state to your component? Also, I didn't understand the part returning the value to true. As far as I know, you can keep your state as a boolean.

Comment: if you show your reducers index.js and connect() It would be easier to find the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you aren't returning the state at all.  You are just replacing it with a boolean.  You probably want to replace a specific part of your state like...

```
return {...state, submitted: false}
```

Comment: Actually, OP returning a state here. The state is just a boolean. Though one can argue doing this is a best practice but at least it should work.

Comment: Sure it's valid to completely dump your incoming state and swap it for a boolean.  But that's neither conventional nor what the OP seems to be struggling with.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that OP wants something like that :) Let's see.

Comment: @devserkan that's exactly what I want. but the above code seems to work when I return true. why is that so ? does redux not allow false boolean values.

Comment: Oh, you mean when you change the state to `false` it does not work? No, it should work like setting it to `true`. Can you update your question and give an example of where and how you get this problem?

Comment: It is simple form submission. it is set to false when the form component is loaded and and set to true when it is submitted. console.log it in the form component render method causes this error.

Comment: Then there must be a problem somewhere else. Changing the state to `true` or `false` can't cause this. Maybe your render method? Maybe your `connect`?